# Can't get data from drupal_http_request result

Tags: files

I'm requesting a zip file from a remote location, and I'm getting some strange affects here. Here is a snippet:

```
$result = drupal_http_request($serviceUrl, $options);
    $file = $result->data;

    dpm($result, 'file result'); //returns the object, and I can see $result->data is a string of characters
    dpm($result->data, 'data'); //But, this is empty
    dpm($file, 'file'); //This is also empty
    dpm($result, 'file result'); // Still shows me the object with $result->data
```

The http request works fine as it returns with a code 200

[image]

I want to use it as follows (example):

```
temp_filename = "my_zip.zip";
$zip_file = fopen($temp_filename, "w+");
fwrite($zip_file, $file); //$file is $result->data, but is empty.
fclose($zip_file);
```

Anybody got an idea why I can't get $result->data?

The code is inside an object method, not a standard PHP function. Not sure if that has anything to do with it.

Also worth mentioning that I can read $result->code and $result->status_message with no problems.

Comment: There's definitely a result in `data`, you can see it in the Krumo output, so you can definitely 'get' it...what problem are you having exactly? It's not possible for `data` to be there and not be there at the same time, and since it's definitely there, I can't imagine what issue you're having. Does the file not get written or is it corrupt? If it's the latter, use a proper method to write the file eg ZipArchive.

Comment: Well that is what's confusing me as well. There is definitely data in the $result object. And the data is definitely a string of characters (which is the content of a zip file). But if I take the data out ($file = $result->data), the $file is blank. I don't need to zip it, it is already a zip file I'm downloading, and I need to unzip it later on.
Maybe I should change my question to: How to download a zip file using drupal_http_request, because I can't find any examples anywhere.

Comment: Probably to do with the fact zip files are binary (you're currently writing as ASCII). Not sure drupal_http_request is the best tool for this particular job. Better to use system_retrieve_file or your favourite standard php method

Comment: Got it working. I need to use drupal_http_request as I am passing custom tokens in header. system_retrieve_file is basically a wrapper for drupal_http_request, where I can't set headers.
And the reason I can't see the data is probably what you said it being binary.
I got it working by re writing it in a standard function putting it all together in one function. Thanks!

Comment: No worries :) It'd be great if you could put in an answer detailing how you solved it, just so this will be useful to future visitors

Answer (score 3):

I got it working myself.
Kudos to Clive who mentioned that the data is binary which probably means why I can't view it with dpm().

In closure, here is a code example to fetch a zip file with drupal_http_request where you can set header information.

```
function MY_MODULE_download_zip($service_url, $token, $request_body) {
    $request_headers = array(
        'Content-Type' => 'text/xml', //sending additional data as XML
        'Content-Length' => strlen($request_body), //See options['data']
        'charset' => 'utf-8',
        'loginToken' => $token, //I needed to pass a login token
        'Cache-Control' => 'no-cache',
        'Pragma' => 'no-cache',
        'Connection' => 'keep-alive'
    );

    $options = array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'headers' => $request_headers,
        'data' => $request_body, //I needed to pass more info here as a XML
        'timeout' => 60.0, //it's a big file
    );
    $result = drupal_http_request($service_url, $options);

    if ($result->code != 200) {
      watchdog('ERROR', 'ERROR: :error', array(':error' => $result->error);
      return FALSE;
    }

    $temp_filename = "my_zip_file.zip";
    $zip_file = fopen($temp_filename, "w+");
    fwrite($zip_file, $result->data);
    fclose($zip_file);

    return TRUE;
}
```